# Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/.../.../prerender-error TypeError: c.props.href.startsWith is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js, build-error

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: c.props.href.startsWith is not a function
    at E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\head.js:123:43
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\head.js:123:15
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at reduceComponents (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\head.js:116:140)
    at emitChange (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\side-effect.js:13:36)
    at SideEffect (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\side-effect.js:19:9)
    at Wc (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

.........

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /
        /_error: /404
        /_error: /500
        /about
        /contact
        /pricing
        /works
        /works/sikhbo-kivabe
    at E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:409:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1398:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1258:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (E:\proftfolio_initial\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:66:29)
```

Dev env running fine. The above error occur when i try to build my project. The error woun't let any page to generate.Dev env running fine. The above error occur when i try to build my project. The error woun't let any page to generate.Dev env running fine. The above error occur when i try to build my project. The error woun't let any page to generate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i was passing href where i should have passed src

What I was doing wrong

```js
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href={logoFC} />
      </Head>
```

What i should've done

```js
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" src={logoFC} />
      </Head>
```